# Как корректно применить css фильтры для работы в большинстве браузеров?

Tags: css, svg, filter

Имеется иконка формата svg, подключение с помощью css background:

```
<li class="decor"><a href="decor.html"><span class="decor-icon"></span></a></li>
```

Проблема в том, что эти фильтры не работают на фаервокс и Microsoft Edge, Ie.
Как можно исправить эту проблему?

На хроме, опере, сафари работает.

CSS:

```
    .decor-icon:before {
        background: url('../images/decor.png') no-repeat;
        background: url('../images/decor.svg') no-repeat;
        content: '';
        height: 92px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -23px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 46px;
    }

    .decor-icon:not(:hover) {
        transition: 2s;
        -webkit-filter: saturate(0%);
        filter: saturate(0%);
    }

    .decor-icon:hover {
        transition: 1s;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение изменить `<span>` на `<img>`.

HTML:

```
<li class="decor">
    <a href="decor.html"><img class="decor-icon" src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/decor.svg'); ?>" /></a>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.decor-icon {
  height: 92px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -23px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 46px;
}

img:not(:hover) {
  transition: 2s;
  -webkit-filter: saturate(0%);
          filter: saturate(0%);
}

img:hover {
  transition: 1s;
}
```

Comment: И как интересно это решение помогло с ИЕ и Эдж?

Comment: Дело в том, что c тэгом img фильтры работают как для картинки в целом, а не именно для SVG. Когда SVG был фоном и использовались фильтры, картинки отсутствовали в некоторых браузерах, сейчас всё работает корректно в Firefox, Adge. Ie нет. Буду рад, если есть более полноценные варианты.

Comment: @Agestor, к сожалению фильтры CSS не очень кроссбраузерны вообще..